# Array Convert to html in powershell

Tags: arrays, powershell

Hi everyone,
             I have a powershell script to get macfee anti-virus version from a list of servers. Here is the script:

```
$a = @()
$serverlist = "serverlist.txt"
foreach ($server in Get-Content $serverlist) 
{ 
$ProductVer = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine',$Computer).OpenSubKey('SOFTWARE\McAfee\DesktopProtection').GetValue('szProductVer')
$EngineVer = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine',$Computer).OpenSubKey('SOFTWARE\McAfee\AVEngine').GetValue('EngineVersionMajor')
$DatVer = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine',$Computer).OpenSubKey('SOFTWARE\McAfee\AVEngine').GetValue('AVDatVersion')
$DatDate = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine',$Computer).OpenSubKey('SOFTWARE\McAfee\AVEngine').GetValue('AVDatDate')

$a += " `n $server - Product version: $ProductVer Engine version: $EngineVer Dat version: $DatVer DatDate $DatDate "
# Write-Host "$server - Product version: $ProductVer Engine version: $EngineVer Dat version: $DatVer DatDate $DatDate"

}

 Write-host $a

 # foreach($_ in $a){ConvertTo-HTML -Body $_,$a.$_ | Out-File D:\Powershell_scripts\list.html}
```

The write host output gives me this output on screen:

```
aucfd208 - Product version: 8.8.0.975 Engine version: 5600 Dat version: 7389 DatDate 2014/03/26
aucfd207 - Product version: 8.8.0.975 Engine version: 5600 Dat version: 7389 DatDate 2014/03/26
au420g18 - Product version: 8.8.0.975 Engine version: 5600 Dat version: 7389 DatDate 2014/03/26
cnche001 - Product version: 8.8.0.975 Engine version: 5600 Dat version: 7389 DatDate 2014/03/26
```

Now I'm confused on how to get in an html format?

If I use `foreach($_ in $a){ConvertTo-HTML -Body $_,$a.$_ | Out-File D:\Powershell_scripts\list.html`, I only get the last line of output:

```
cnche001 - Product version: 8.8.0.975 Engine version: 5600 Dat version: 7389 DatDate 2014/03/26
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try slightly different approach - first take the input into csv-like form. This should be fairly easy:

```
$a = @()
$serverlist = "serverlist.txt"
$outputCSV = "report.csv"
"Server;ProductVer;EngineVer;DatVer;DatDate" | Out-File -Append $outputCSV
foreach ($server in Get-Content $serverlist) 
{ 
$ProductVer = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine',$Computer).OpenSubKey('SOFTWARE\McAfee\DesktopProtection').GetValue('szProductVer')
$EngineVer = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine',$Computer).OpenSubKey('SOFTWARE\McAfee\AVEngine').GetValue('EngineVersionMajor')
$DatVer = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine',$Computer).OpenSubKey('SOFTWARE\McAfee\AVEngine').GetValue('AVDatVersion')
$DatDate = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine',$Computer).OpenSubKey('SOFTWARE\McAfee\AVEngine').GetValue('AVDatDate')

$Server + ";" + $ProductVer + ";" + $EngineVer + ";" + $DatVer + ";" + $DatDate | out-file -Append $outputCSV
} 

$CSVform = Import-Csv -Delimiter ";" $outputCSV
$CSVform | ConvertTo-Html | Out-File "HTMLReport.html"
```

This should generate a simple HTML output you are looking for. There will be no eye candy and stuff, but this is up to your invention how you want the script to work :-)

As for the question why your script gave only last line, I assume it is because it was missing -Append switch - each line was overwritten with previous one. Similar to '>' and '>>' redirector in command-line.

Hope that clarifies a bit.

Best regards
AlexP

Comment: As for HTML reports, I am going to take a closer look how to utilize XLSes from WMIC. It gives nice, well looking output. Try wmic process list brief /format:htable > SomeHTML.html . WMIC uses HTML XLS files in wbem dir, and I guess we could programatically use these to construct nice reports

Answer (score 0):

Depends how you want the output. If you just want the `$a` array in the body you can do:

`ConvertTo-HTML -Body $a | Out-File D:\Powershell_scripts\list.html`